# Checking correct url and title page automatically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to create a method that I'm going to check whether the page is loaded with the correct URL and title.
My code pass several times, several times fall.
This is my error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Checking if http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/accessories/ contains: imacs
```

This is my code:

```
public void showNavigationLinks() {

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        String[] submenu = {"Accessories", "iMacs", "iPads" , "iPhones" , "iPods" , "MacBook"};

        for(int i=0; i < submenu.length; i++) {

            WebElement productCategory = waitForElementToBeDisplayed(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Product Category')]"), 5000);
            action = action.moveToElement(productCategory);

            WebElement submenuItem = waitForElementToBeDisplayed(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + submenu[i] + "')]"), 5000);
            action.moveToElement(submenuItem).click().build().perform();

            String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            String title = driver.getTitle();

            Assert.assertTrue("Checking if " + currentUrl + " contains: " + submenu[i].toLowerCase(),
                    currentUrl.contains(submenu[i].toLowerCase()));

            Assert.assertTrue("Checking if title contains: " + submenu[i],
                    title.contains(submenu[i]));
            System.out.println(title);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify that navigation links are leading to correct page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960839/verify-that-navigation-links-are-leading-to-correct-page)

Comment: It's hard for me to tell how this is different than the previous 6 questions you have asked? I think I've seen this same question posed by someone else as well recently. Please delete some of your questions to avoid duplicates. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the AssertionError is because your assertion has failed. The URL being fetched is  "http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/accessories/" whereas you are expecting the url to contain the word "imacs" (I suppose you are expecting the URL to be  http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/imacs/) which causes the assertion to fail.

In your code, you are waiting for the submenu item "imacs" to be displayed and you then click on the submenu option and verify if the URL for the submenu option has loaded. This action will not yield the same result always, as the page may take a while to load and you may possibly be fetching the previous URL. I suggest to wait till the new page has loaded completely before fetching the URL and title of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Try following: {It doesn't use assert but it prints title and url only if they are matching to your submenu entries:

```
package package1;

import java.awt.AWTException;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class new1 {

static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/accessories/");

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    showNavigationLinks() ;

}

public static void showNavigationLinks() {

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    String[] submenu = {"Accessories", "iMacs", "iPads" , "iPhones" , "iPods" , "MacBook"};

    for(int i=0; i < submenu.length; i++) {

        WebElement productCategory = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Product Category')]"));
        action = action.moveToElement(productCategory);

        WebElement submenuItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + submenu[i] + "')]"));
        action.moveToElement(submenuItem).click().build().perform();

        String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        String title = driver.getTitle();

        if(currentUrl.contains(submenu[i].toLowerCase())){

            System.out.println("CurrentUrl is " + currentUrl + "  " + submenu[i].toLowerCase());

        }



        if(title.contains(submenu[i])){

            System.out.println("title is " + title + "  " + submenu[i]);

        }



    }

}
```

}

Comment: This code works, but not always work as you expect. It happens to pass a test does not check all parties expect. I put wait to wait for the item or it did not help.

Comment: I didn't get " It happens to pass a test does not check all parties expect.", can you explain?

Comment: My problem is that it has not arrived to a loaded already started checking whether the correct side and throw an error. I tried to wait, but it did not help. I used
waitForElementToBeDisplayed.